# How to keep sausage cases from splitting?

Tags: meat, sausages

I make the sausage mix and put it in the casing. Although, when I twist them to make them into individual sausages it splits and I have wasted the casing and sausage meat.

The sausages split literally as I twist them. I use 'Single dry beef collagen casing 28mm' cases. I store them in a dark safe cupboard where they cannot get damaged. Before filling them I wash the to make sure they are no snags

Any help would be appreciated,
Domford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collagen casings are quite fragile, unfortunately, and can’t easily be twisted off. You can try filling them less and pinching the meat away in the area you’ll twist, or tying them off with kitchen twine, or use natural casings instead.

Comment: Hi @Sneftel, thank you so much! Would you be able to recommend any brands of natural casings. Thanks, Domford

Comment: Afraid not, it’s been many years since I did any sausage-making. Ask your local butcher.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! I hope you stay well in these unpredictable times :)